# Calculating pressure forces (vertical) on a curve surface

Tags: fluid-mechanics, fluid

I am particularly confused about finding pressure forces (specifically vertical force) on a curve surface. Although I understand the general method is to use sum of forces in the x/y direction (ie by considering the liquid weight above and so on) and find resultant force that way. I have been practising a lot of problems lately and this is one of them:

[image]
[image]

So here are all my attempts:

For the pressure diagram I did, this because pressure vary linearly.

[image]

For the horizontal force:
$F_H=\:\frac{1}{2} \times \rho \times g \times h^2 \times b$
Or in this case, $h = D = 4$ and $b = B = 5$

**Vertical force (my confusion):**

Is the sum of forces in the y-direction equals the weight of the liquid? Or does this also include the unknown $F$? In other words, is $F_y = F + W$ or just $F_y = W$?

Also what is the equation $x = \frac{y^2}{A}$ for? I am guessing you can use that to find the self weight? ie  $W = mg = \rho V g = \gamma A w$, in this case $A = A_2$

[image]

for $D$ = 4, $x = \frac{D^2}{4}=4$

$A_1 + A_2 = x \times D$

$A_1$ can be found by integration, $A_1=\:\int _0^D\:\frac{y^2}{4}dy\:\:=\:\frac{1}{12}D^3,\:\:D\:=\:4,\:A_1\:=\:\frac{1}{12}\left(4\right)^3$

So is$F_y = W$ Only?

d) For the last part, I assume you need to make moment at the hinge? But then how can I calculate this distance from the self weight of the fluid to the hinge?

Comment: Hmmm.I having the same issue too with figuring out the vertical forces, but in my problem the curve of the dam looks a bit different. I definitely want to see a solution to this question.

Comment: @SolarMike Hi solar Mike, yes I have been practising a lot. I upvoted and accepted the answer from r13 for my recent problem. I hope you don't mind, I just want to understand the concepts and I put a lot of effort into those questions.

Comment: I suggest reviewing this article. Pay attention to case 2 of the subject labeled "Total Hydrostatic Force on Curved Surfaces". https://mathalino.com/reviewer/fluid-mechanics-and-hydraulics/total-hydrostatic-force-plane-and-curved-surfaces

Comment: @r13 Thanks for the article really helps for finding the vertical force, But now I don't know how to find the centroid of the irregular shape, I think this is my last part as now I can take moment about hinge and solve. Many thanks again

Comment: @r13 Actually I think I solved it. I found the centroid of the area above the boundary. But I am still unsure what the pressure diagram looks like.

Comment: The vertical pressure diagram is the same shape as the gate - a curve between zero and the maximum pressure. (image the water is above the gate)

Comment: @r13 What about the pressure diagram for both x and y acting on the gate? Is it still the same shape as the gate?

Comment: Important hints - 1) Water pressure is acting "normal" to the contact surface. 2) On a submerged particle, the water pressure is acting radially all around it with an identical intensity. Hint 1 should answer your question, I'll explain 2) further in my answer, which will come later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope the sketches below help the understanding of this problem. Note, the concept below holds true for any shape of the gate (straight/curved concave up/down). The difference lies in finding the volume and weight/force center of the respective shapes.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

$$x=y^2/4m \quad y=1/2\sqrt{x} :\ for\ y=4,\quad x=4 $$

The vertical force is the sum of infinitesimal small forces that are maximum at x=0, h=D and decrease by the following

$$F_v=\rho(d-1/2\int \sqrt{x}dx)$$.
Assuming $$rho=1000kg/m^3 \quad F_v=1000(4-1/2\frac{2}{3}x^{3/2})=1000/3*/4^{3/2})=1000(4-2.66)=1333.3kg$$

This force works at a height of the Sum of the

$infinitesimal$ $\int\rho*ydx$ forces multiplied by their centroids, $y/2$ divided by the total force $F_v$.

$ \bar{D}= 1/2 *1/2\frac{ \int_{0}^{D} x \sqrt{x} dx}{F_v} =1/4*2/5 \frac{x^{5/2}}{2.666}=0.1*32/1.333=1.203m$

Now we calculate the Horizontal force on the gate and its centroid.

Then we set the sum of the moments equal to zero $M_{F_v}+ M_{F_h}+M_F=0$

Check my arithmetics. I did not have time to double-check.

Comment: Hi Kamran thanks for the answer, does the pressure diagram that I have drawn make sense? Thanks.

Comment: @CountDOOKU, No! You are confused by the curve of the gate. The water pressure is independent of the shape of its container. It just is always P= rho*h. In this case, too you drop a vertical line and graph the triangular pressure distribution.  if you like to lay it on the gate you should substitute the x in Y=1/2sqrt(x) to x+rho*D so y= 1/2 sqrt(x+rho*D).

Comment: So I don't draw my pressure diagram on the gate? But my pressure diagram includes both x and y components no? Not just the x component so why is it always $\rho g h$? I though I think my diagram is wrong. Many thanks again sir.

Comment: Check your math